# Homepage Content Moving Inside Eachother When Re-sizing?

Tags: html, css

For some reason this issue just popped up and wasn't happening before. I'm not sure what I changed.

Issue: when I re-size my website, all the content on the homepage moves inside each other. This wasn't happening before I pushed an update today and I'm not sure what I broke.

Here is the entire website download: https://github.com/Sphiinxx/SimplyEating

Thanks!

Comment: You should git checkout your previous commit and then use "diff" to compare it to the latest one and you will find the change that broke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the height which you have specified in every section. eg

```
.eathealthy-section {
/* height: 75%; */
padding-top: 75px; 
text-align: center;
background: #eee;
}
```

Remove the `height:75%` and you should be fine, do the same for all section heights